# Check if object is null before accessing member, OR assign non-null alternative

Tags: c#, null, conditional-operator

We're using .NET Standard 2.1 / C# 8.0. and I'm looking for something that's a variant of a null-coalescing operator / null conditional operator / ternary operator.

A simplified version of the code I've got, which works is:

`studentPhoneNumber = (student.PhoneNumber != null) ? student.PhoneNumber.Number : "None specified"`

`studentPhoneNumber` is a string

`PhoneNumber` is itself a class, which can be null if the student hasn't set it yet.

I'd rather this said something like:

`studentPhoneNumber = student.PhoneNumber?.Number : "None specified"`

but the variations of this that I've tried don't work.

I'm aware of Fowler's Null Object Pattern and Law of Demeter, and that applying them could make this easier, but it would be a huge change in our codebase.

For now, I was just looking for some sort of operator that would make this read easier.

Comment: What about `studentPhoneNumber = student.PhoneNumber?.Number ?? "None specified"`?

Comment: use this ``student.PhoneNumber?.Number ??  "None specified";``

Comment: Look through [null-coalescing assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), as pointed in other comments

Comment: Thanks UnholySheep and Sajid - your suggestion works... or at least it would work if I wasn't deep in some Entity Framework code, which doesn't allow its usage.  Thanks anyway - good to know for other scenarios.

Comment: Do one of you guys want to suggest that as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0):

@Sajid and @UnholySheep answers:

```
student.PhoneNumber?.Number ?? "None specified";
```